# subprocess.Popen(): change stderr during child's execution

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, tcpdump

**Goal:** I'm trying to put a Python script together that captures the network traffic that occurs as a result of the execution of a block of code. For simplicity, let's assume I want to log the network traffic resulting from a call to `socket.gethostbyname('example.com')`. Note: I can't just simply terminate `tcpdump` when `gethostbyname()` returns as the actual code block that I want to measure triggers other external code, and I have no way to determine when this external code finishes execution (so I have to leave `tcpdump` running "long enough" for it to be highly probable that I logged all traffic generated by this external code).

**Approach:** I'm using `subprocess` to start `tcpdump`, telling `tcpdump` to terminate itself after `duration` seconds using its `-G` and `-W` options, e.g.:

```
duration = 15
nif = 'en0'
pcap = 'dns.pcap'
cmd = ['tcpdump', '-G', str(duration), '-W', '1', '-i', nif, '-w', pcap]
tcpdump_proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
socket.gethostbyname('example.com')
time.sleep(duration + 5) # sleep longer than tcpdump is running
```

The problem with this is that `Popen()` returns *before* `tcpdump` is fully up and running, thus some/all of the traffic resulting from the call to `gethostbyname()` will not be captured. I could obviously add a `time.sleep(x)` before calling `gethostbyname()` to give `tcpdump` a bit of time to spin up, but that's not a portable solution (I can't just pick some arbitrary `x < duration` as a powerful system would start capturing packets earlier than a less powerful system).

To deal with this, my idea is to parse `tcpdump`'s output to look for when the following is written to its `stderr` as that appears to indicate that the capture is up and running fully:

```
tcpdump: listening on en0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

Thus I need to attach to `stderr`, but the problem is that I don't want to commit to reading all of its output as I need my code to move on to actually execute the code block I want to measure (`gethostbyname()` in this example) instead of being stuck in a loop reading from `stderr`.

I could solve this by adding a semaphore that blocks the main thread from proceeding onto the `gethostbyname()` call, and have a background thread read from `stderr` and decrement the semaphore (to let the main thread move on) when it reads the string above from `stderr`, but I'd like to keep the code single-threaded if possible.

From my understanding, it's a big NONO to use `subprocess.PIPE` for `stderr` and `stdout` without committing to reading all of the output as the child will end up blocking when the buffer fills up. But can you "detach" (destroy?) the pipe mid execution if you're only interested in reading the first part of the output? Essentially I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
duration = 15
nif = 'en0'
pcap = 'dns.pcap'
cmd = ['tcpdump', '-G', str(duration), '-W', '1', '-i', nif, '-w', pcap]
tcpdump_proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
for l in tcpdump_proc.stderr:
    if 'tcpdump: listening on' in l:
        break
socket.gethostbyname('example.com')
time.sleep(duration) # sleep at least as long as tcpdump is running
```

What else do I need to add within the `if` block to "reassign" who's in charge of reading `stderr`? Can I just set `stderr` back to `None` (`tcpdump_proc.stderr = None`)? Or should I call `tcpdump_proc.stderr.close()` (and will `tcpdump` terminate early if I do so)?

It could also very well be that I missed something obvious and that there is a much better approach to achieve what I want - if so, please enlighten me :).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why not just continue after the **dns.pcap** capture file is created?  That happens **after** the *"listening on"* message is written to `stderr`, so it occurs even closer to when `tcpdump` is fully ready.  As a bonus, you also won't ever have to worry about what the exact text of the *"listening on"* message written to `stderr` is, so if it should ever change, it will be inconsequential to you.  Just be sure to delete the capture file before starting `tcpdump`, just in case the file already exists.

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard That's neat, thanks a ton for this information! I was assuming that the file would be created first (to have somewhere to store packets) _before_ `tcpdump` starts to listen for packets (and prints "listening on"). How did you figure out it's the other way around? From the source code? If so, do you mind sharing where exactly, please (I couldn't find it myself, sorry)?

Comment: Yes, I looked at the source code from https://www.tcpdump.org/index.html#latest-releases

Comment: OK, I had actually looked at an older 4.1.1. release.  The latest 4.9.3 is slightly different and it seems the "listening on" message is now printed **after** the capture file has been opened, which is what you'd expect, I guess.  Still, if you wait for the file to be created, I think that should be sufficient for your purposes.  Well, it's an option in case you want to explore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `detach()` or `close()` on stderr after recieving the `listening on` message:

```
import subprocess
import time

duration = 10
nif = 'eth0'
pcap = 'dns.pcap'
cmd = ['tcpdump', '-G', str(duration), '-W', '1', '-i', nif, '-w', pcap]

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd, shell=False, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, text=True
)
for i, line in enumerate(proc.stderr):
    print('read %d lines from stderr' % i)
    if 'listening on' in line:
        print('detach stderr!')
        proc.stderr.detach()
        break

while proc.poll() is None:
    print("doing something else while tcpdump is runnning!")
    time.sleep(2)

print(proc.returncode)
print(proc.stderr.read())
```

Out:

```
read 0 lines from stderr
detach stderr!
doing something else while tcpdump is runnning!
doing something else while tcpdump is runnning!
doing something else while tcpdump is runnning!
doing something else while tcpdump is runnning!
doing something else while tcpdump is runnning!
doing something else while tcpdump is runnning!
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(proc.stderr.read())
ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached
```

Note:

I haven't checked what is **really** happening to the stderr data, but detaching stderr doesn't seem to have any impact on tcpdump.